# Excel - Create multiple folders and hyperlinks

Tags: vba, excel

I want/need to select cells on an Excel worksheet and create folders (called the same as the cell text) and also hyperlink the cell to the newly created folder.

I have managed to find a VBA that creates folders for selected cells and they are saving in the same location as the excel is saved....great saves me loads of time!

....but I would like to add to the VBA that the cell should link to the created folder, can anyone help? This is to save me hyperlinking each individual cell.

I wish I knew how to create these myself as I am amazed this looks like the matrix to me!

Below is the VBA that works to create the list of folders as per the name of the cell (I got this from forum):

```
Sub MakeFolders()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer

    Set Rng = Selection
    maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
    maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count

    For c = 1 To maxCols

        r = 1
        Do While r <= maxRows

            If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then

                MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c))
                On Error Resume Next
            End If

            r = r + 1
        Loop

    Next c

End Sub
```

Appreciate your help and please excuse my lack of knowledge with regard to this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.  I've replace your MakeFolders procedure with a shorter version.

```
Public Sub MakeHyperlinks()

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim rCell As Range

    'List your folders in range A1:A4 - e.g. S:\Bartrup-CookD\Test\My New Folder 1
    Set MyRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4")

    For Each rCell In MyRange
        'Create the folder.
        CreateFolder rCell.Value

        'Create the hyperlink.
        rCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rCell, _
                             Address:=Replace(rCell.Value, " ", "%20")

    Next rCell

End Sub

Public Sub CreateFolder(Folder)
On Error Resume Next
Dim objFSO As Object: Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Folder <> "" Then
        If Not objFSO.FileExists(objFSO.GetParentFolderName(Folder)) Then
            Call CreateFolder(objFSO.GetParentFolderName(Folder))
        End If
        objFSO.CreateFolder (Folder)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works perfectly and saves me a lot of time.